# Did anyone know how to install Magento 1.9.2 Plugins on PHP7?

Tags: magento, plugins, magento-1.9, php-7

I try to install Plugins on my Magento 1.9.2.4 on PHP 7.0.4.

All normal Plugins have the same Error Message:

```
requires PHP version >= 5.2.13 and <= 5.7.0 current is: 7.0.4
```

The Shop runs after a small bugfix fine. But without Plugins its Useless.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 5):

The creator of each extension/plugin in Magento specifies a supported version.  It sounds like none of your plugins/extensions support PHP anything greater than a (existent) PHP 5.7.  You'll either need to

1. Contact extension/plugin vendors and ask them to release a version on connect that supports PHP 7
2. Stop using Magento Connect to install plugins and install them yourselves manually.

The specifics of this are well beyond the scope of an individual Stack Overflow answer.